# Dojo CircularLinearGauge and noChange property

Tags: dojo

Here's likely some easily won points for someone...

I've got the following simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    require(["dojo/parser"] , function( parser ) {
            parser.parse();
        }
    );

</script>
<div id="livingroom" data-dojo-type="dojox/dgauges/components/default/CircularLinearGauge" noChange="true"
     value="0" minimum="-50" maximum="50" style="width:300px; height:300px; left:80px; top:0px; position: absolute;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows a gauge just as expected. However, the attribute "noChange" has no effect and the needle of the gauge can be moved - can someone please tell me what is wrong? Also, according to the API reference,the default value is be "true" for this setting so it seems that it is not used at all?

Dojo 1.8 is installed locally.

(I'm heading off to bed so any further clarification will have to wait until morning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noChange` was a supported property in the old, now deprecated, gauge framework in Dojo. The old gauge framework (before 1.8) was in **dojox/gauges** and the new one is in **dojox/dgauges**. Since you are using the new framework, the property you should use is the `interactionArea` and its value should be set to `none`. For more information see the [dgauges framework documentation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/dgauges#setting-properties-using-markup).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, darn...so I've been looking at the wrong version of the documentation? So much time wasted... :( Thank you for your answer, I had nearly given up on this.